# Is it possible to run a full node lightning network bitcoin core 22.0 on a 32 bit computer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, full-node, taproot

I have an old pc with Atom N270 that I would like to use as full node, how can I do that?

[image: screenshot download bitcoin core]

Comment: Bitcoin core yes, if you can figure out how to compile. but do note you'll need to run lightning in a 64 bit machine since `channel.db` will exceed 2gb causing lightning to crash.  https://github.com/pangyuteng/bitcoin-lndhub

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin Core 22.0 only supports 64-bit x86 platforms. The Atom N270 is a 32-bit CPU, so it is not supported.

It *may* be possible to compile the 22.0 source code yourself for a 32-bit platform however, and the result may still work. But you're on your own then.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an old pc with Atom N270 that I would like to use as full node, how can I do that?

As you can see from [the list of pre-compiled 22.0 binaries](https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/), there is no Intel 32-bit option available. There is a 32-bit ARM version available, but your Atom N270 is an Intel processor not an ARM processor.

Therefore, you will have to download the source code and try to compile it yourself to get the node running on the Atom N270 computer.

There are [installation from source instruction specific to Linux/Ubuntu here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#linux-distribution-specific-instructions), which might be easiest to follow, assuming you are able to install a 32-bit Ubuntu operating system on your computer.